# System Call implementation

Tags: system-calls

I am trying to extend the system call for `my_time`.

I am extending timekeeping.c for it. But its giving me random time.

```
struct timeval tv;

// get the current time
do_gettimeofday(&tv);
current_time->tv_sec=tv.tv_sec;
current_time->tv_nsec=tv.tv_usec*1000;

return( current_time->tv_nsec);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
Actually time is nanoseconds so its not random. Its just for each seconds its showing high deviation